# Автоподстройка ширины окна под виджет QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

Доброго времени суток. Совсем только начинаю знакомится qt, возник вопрос по отображению. Есть три QPushButton, они соединены в одну QHBoxLayout. Есть QTableWidget, он соединен с QHBoxLAyout в одну QVBoxLayout. В QTableWidget по нажатию кнопок добавляются строки с содержимым, ширина столбцов меняется. Но как сделать так, чтобы и размер окна программы был закреплен за размерами QTableWidget (число столбцов известно и не меняется) и таких вот ситуаций не возникало: [image: скриншот программы]  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ну и в обратную сторону, чтобы не было скролла, а окна подстраивалось, если вдруг ячейка увеличивается в размере
[image]

Comment: Есть один вариант и он простой: `table->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);`

Comment: Но ведь в обратную сторону этот метод не работает, если вдруг размер окна увеличивается, то появляется скролл, а значит привязки размера окна к ширине таблицы все еще нет

Comment: По мне так, увеличение размера окна на размер таблицы внутри него плохая идея. Но если вам это так нужно, тогда можно перехватывать событие увеличения таблицы (повесить фильтр событий или переопределить виджет) и размер таблицы устанавливать как минимальный размер (или даже фиксированный) у главного окна